How do i add Attachments to Devops via api using make.com
I am integrating clickup to Azure devops (using make.com) and i want that when an issue is updated with attachements on clickup then the file should be attached to devops also.
I understand there is no readily available module on make.com. Is there any api request which i can use to upload attachment to Devops from clickup.
Thanks
I tried using make.com but it does not have a module

To upload attachment to DevOps, you should user DevOps rest api. And it needs two steps to add attachment to work item. Please check the details below, let me know if you have any queries.


Is there any api request which i can use to upload attachment to Devops from clickup.

To upload attachment to DevOps work item, there are 2 steps to do:

Use rest api Attachments - Create to create the attachment. On accounts with higher attachment upload limits (>130MB), you will need to use chunked upload.

You cannot see the attachment yet, need to link the attachment to work item via rest api Work Items - Update


You can check the similar ticket for more details.
